# Dynamically formArray creating

Tags: ionic3, angular5, angular4-forms

I have a formgroup name `studentRegistrationForm`. In this form i want to create
dynamically `studentList` array but i can not done this.

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.studentRegistrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      session: ['', [Validators.required]],
      semester: ['', [Validators.required]],
      students: ['',[Validators.required]],
      studentList: this.formBuilder.array([
      ]),
    });

    let control = <FormArray>this.studentRegistrationForm.controls['studentList'];


    this.studentRegistrationForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe( data => {
        if(data.semester  && data.session && data.students){
          control.push(this.createStudent());
        }

      });
}

  createStudent() {
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('',Validators.required)
    })
  }
```

[image: here is my error picture]

Comment: It is most likely because you are modifying the form (the `studentList` form control is in the form) every time a value in the form changes... which triggers another form change... etc.

Comment: Actually I give a condition which is execute at a certain value .. so is it call inside for everytime

Comment: If you have a suggestion plz give answer how I can achieve this with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your issue is that you're subscribing to form changes, which then adds more data to the form, which triggers form changes, and so on until you reach the stack limit.

Without further context to what your use case, my suggestion would be to remove the subscription to form changes and instead add a button for adding a new student to the list, which you can disable unless the current form is valid (similar to the logic that you already have in place):

```
<div formArrayName="studentList" class="well well-lg">
    <div *ngFor="let student of students.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <label for="id">ID:</label><input formControlName="id">
        <label for="id">EMail:</label><input formControlName="email">
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="doCreateStudent()" [disabled]="!studentRegistrationForm.valid">Add Student</button>
</div>
```

As you have validators defined for semester, session and students fields already, you can just use `studentRegistrationForm.valid` to test validity before allowing a new student to be added.

Here's a minimal stackblitz demonstrating your code working without the error:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcfbyr

Comment: actually i need dynamically create student . depends of number of  students. if input is 4 then 4 array elements are create .

Comment: Ok, next time add this requirement to your question. Updated the Stackblitz to show how you can do this with a button - you can subscribe to valueChanges on the students field if you want, but that might frustrate IMO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396222/write-multiple-row-at-a-time  please check this @chrisWhite